# Model Object C#

Tags: c#, api, drawing, object-model

i am working in a compnay for training, and they asked me to do a modeling application.
to be clear, i want to code using C# an application that do as same as the "logic works" or "Visio".
why dont they use those? because they want to use different items, plus they want it to be stored in a database not as a file with extention.

so, i searched but i couldn't find any ready API that i can use to make it easier for me.
you know its hard to do it from scratch.
i just want the area to be ready, and i can add items the way i like, so i can append them to the drawing area, then link them. at the end the user will click on "Calculate". it will show a statistical and analytical information that will help them in planning!!

so any one here has any idea about any library that could help me in this situation,
am coding using C#

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I agree with nobugz... it sounds like quite a challenging project to undertake, and you are not going to get the functionality and flexibility that you will get from an app like Visio without some serious manpower and effort. So I would try and go the interop route.

BUT if that isn't an option, then you are definitely going to want something that utilizes WPF, as it really simplifies the whole presentation aspect.

There is a project that I used from "Code Project" as a base startup called [Draw Tools](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_DrawTools.aspx) which was a great start as it shows the basics, having a canvas, and dragging objects and shapes onto the canvas - all in C#, and really gave us a jump start.

Good Luck!

Comment: Nice link!  You might want to suggest it in answer to this question:   My linked-to CodeProject app doesn't "look eye candy", but I'm sure WPF can "look eye candy".

Answer (score 1):

Users have *very* expectations for the user interface for such a program.  It both needs to look good and be flexible.  Doing this yourself isn't advisable, it is a major work item and a never-ending maintenance headache.  Before you dismiss a commercial solution, be sure to take a look at their automation interface.  The one for Visio is in the [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc160740.aspx) namespace.  Storing data to a dbase is certainly possible with it.